# How to use NetBidirectionalOperator?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm a little uncertain as how to use `NetBidirectionalOperator`. In other frameworks, switching an LSTM to be bidirectional is an option but you have to double the dimensions of the linear layer directly after it.

There are no "application" examples in the documentation center so I'm hoping someone might provide one and show how it works with labels and targets during training. *Do I have to reverse and concatenate the inputs?*

Here's a toy example of a net (that predicts the last character in a word) to get started:

```
net = NetInitialize @ NetChain[{UnitVectorLayer[], 
    NetBidirectionalOperator @ BasicRecurrentLayer[20], 
    SequenceLastLayer[], LinearLayer[97], SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder["Characters"], 
   "Input" -> NetEncoder["Characters"]];
data = Table[With[{r = RandomWord[]}, 
    StringTake[r, ;; -2] -> StringTake[r, -1]], 10];
NetTrain[NetStateObject[net], data, All]
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this example](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/05/24/learning-to-listen-neural-networks-application-for-recognizing-speech/) help.

Comment: Thanks. It says that it doubles the sequence length - but that I did know. It's a good example but I'm looking for how it works with generating text.

Answer (score 3):

```
net = NetGraph[
  <|
   "net" -> {
     UnitVectorLayer[],
     NetBidirectionalOperator@BasicRecurrentLayer[20],
     SequenceLastLayer[],
     LinearLayer[97],
     SoftmaxLayer[]
     },
   "last" -> SequenceLastLayer[],
   "loss" -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> "net" -> NetPort["loss", "Input"],
   NetPort["Target"] -> "last" -> NetPort["loss", "Target"]
   },
  "Input" -> NetEncoder["Characters"],
  "Target" -> NetEncoder["Characters"]
  ]
```

[image]

```
data = Table[With[{r = RandomWord[]}, StringTake[r, ;; -2] -> StringTake[r, -1]],10]
```

> {"ima" -> "m", "stoppin" -> "g", "digestiv" -> "e", 
>    "conventionalit" -> "y", "interactio" -> "n", "hedge" -> "r", 
>    "stabl" -> "y", "bowspri" -> "t", "bur" -> "p", "ingrainin" -> "g"}

```
netT = NetTrain[net, <|"Input" -> data[[;; , 1]], "Target" -> data[[;; , 2]]|>, All]

netT2 = NetReplacePart[
  NetExtract[netT["TrainedNet"], "net"],
  {
   "Input" -> NetEncoder["Characters"],
   "Output" -> NetDecoder["Characters"]
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
netT2@data[[2, 1]]
```

> "g"

**Generating text**

```
gen[start_String, n_Integer] :=
 Module[
  {sobj, next},
  Reap[
     Sow[start];
     sobj = NetStateObject[
       netT2,
       <|
        {2, "ForwardNet", "State"} -> ConstantArray[0, 20],
        {2, "BackwardNet", "State"} -> ConstantArray[0, 20]
        |>
       ];
     Sow[next = sobj@start];
     Do[
      sobj = NetStateObject[
        netT2,
        <|
         {2, "ForwardNet", "State"} -> 
          NetExtract[sobj, "States"][{2, "ForwardNet", "State"}][[1]],
         {2, "BackwardNet", "State"} -> ConstantArray[0, 20]
         |>
        ];
      Sow[next = sobj@next],
      {n - 1}
      ]
     ][[2, 1]] // StringJoin
  ]
```

```
gen["abc", 15]
```

> "abcsssssssyyyyyyyy"

Comment: Thanks, but why is there an extra SequenceLastLayer

Comment: Output of `NetEncoder["Characters"]` is `{"Varying", Restricted["Integer", 97]}` and `CrossEntropyLossLayer` expects `{Restricted["Integer", 97]}` as input. We need to remove "Varying" dimension.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Thanks! Would you mind adding how things would change if we wanted to switch from "word -> next character" to "word -> next word" type training data (with some vocabulary of words)?

Comment: @M.R. It's very easy to do. In `net` replace: `LinearLayer[97]` with `LinearLayer[40236]`, `"Target" -> NetEncoder["Characters"]` with `"Target" -> NetEncoder["Tokens"]`. `data = Table[RandomWord[] -> RandomWord[], 10]`. In `netT2` replace: `"Output" -> NetDecoder["Characters"]` with `"Output" -> NetDecoder["Tokens"]`. That's all!